Identical phones with identical app and identical setup; one can find bluetooth devices the other cannot
I have several smartphones of the same model. Five of them I have been using for testing and building an app. Now I have to deploy the app the the other smartphones I have had laying in a drawer. However, these cannot function like the first few phones I have been testing with, even when they are updated to the same OS version, have the same app permissions, are connected to the same network and all. EVERYTHING is identical between the phones, the new ones just cannot find bluetooth devices when searching in my app, while the old ones can.
Both can find bluetooth devices when searching through the phones buildt in bluetooth menu. I even did a factory reset of one of the old phones I have been testing on, and build the app to it like a brand new and it still worked.
I have no idea where to even start looking for an error. To me it seems like there is just something wrong with the new phones I have. It is just unlikely that the same thing would be wrong with all of them.
I have looked through the system log in Android Studio and the only somewhat similar thing i can find is that the new phones do find something, but maybe skips adding them to the list of bluetooth devices?
I get this on new phones:
2024-05-02 14:00:38.037 22371-22398 BtGatt.GattService      com.android.bluetooth                V  Skipping data matching denylist: ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=-1, mServiceUuids=null, mServiceSolicitationUuids=[], mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[2, 21, 80, 118, 92, -73, -39, -22, 78, 33, -103, -92, -6, -121, -106, 19, -92, -110, 106, 94, 35, 4, -50]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null]
2024-05-02 14:00:38.037 22371-22398 BtGatt.GattService      com.android.bluetooth                I  Skipping client for location deny list

For the old phones I get this when finding a device:
2024-05-02 13:29:54.868 18185-18185 ScanDeviceCtrl          com.example.app2         I  onScanResult: ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=[d1560100-32d8-ee21-19a8-7439819a87a6], mServiceSolicitationUuids=[], mManufacturerSpecificData={1565=[33, -68, -127, -115, -31, -10, 26, -35, 0]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=A8D81]

2024-05-02 13:29:54.868 18185-18185 ScanDeviceCtrl          com.example.app2         I  DeviceName: A8D81

2024-05-02 13:29:54.868 18185-18185 ScanDeviceCtrl          com.example.app2         I  ServiceData: {}

2024-05-02 13:29:54.868 18185-18185 ScanDeviceCtrl          com.example.app2         I  Battery Level: 2880 mV


Possibly on your new phones your apps don't actually have location permission. It feels like you're requesting permission, but that it has not been granted. You could check in the Settings app, or consider fully uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

When I check the permissions under Appinfo the app has permission for finding nearby devices, Location, and Notifications. I there another way to grant the permissions, other than requesting in the app or giving them manually in appinfo?
Fully uninstalling the app, is it enough to just tap the app and choose uninstall, or is there a way to do it "more fully"? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling with no results.

What phones are you using and what Android version are they running? Can you also try using another BLE app such as nRF Connect and let us know if you see the same problem there?

I have found that the app needs, but does not ask for or in any way indicate need for a permission, to be able to know the location of the phone itself in order to be able to find bluetooth devices. I found an option under Settings > Privacy >Permission manager > Location. This needs to be on to allow: "Apps with this permission can access this device's location" - Enabling this made it possible to find devices on the new phones as well.
